# Obtaining asterisk ring groups with asterisk-java

Tags: java, asterisk

We are developing an asterisk PBX based application that consist of 3 parts: 
front end, backend, and asterisk server that handles calls, voicemails, ring groups etc. We managed to integrate `asterisk-java` library and now I wonder if it is possible to obtain the ring groups we defined in `extensions.conf` using this library. I went through the classes and I did not find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no way do that in general way

Only "real" way is do asterisk "COMMAND dialplan show" via AMI and parse dialplan

But in most project it done via versa: dialplan holded in database where you can easy see ringgroups and extensions.conf generated when changed or do lookup in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting off with a new project, you might consider using ARI instead and create ring-groups programmatically. There is a good ARI interface for Java and it's not that hard to use.

Comment: How do you use ARI to access Ring Groups? There does not seem to be any resource for it. Using ari/asterisk/config/dynamic requires a resource. for instance res_pjsip to create endpoints etc. But there isn't any for Ring Groups. Unless I missed something? Would be very useful if this existed however.